# select insert into not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to insert a number of ids into a new table. The list of ids is taken from another table.

My Code:

```
     $stmt = $con->prepare('DROP TABLE tblname;
                            CREATE TABLE tblname (
                                id BIGINT
                                );

                            INSERT INTO tblname (id)
                            SELECT tablename2.colname
                            FROM tablename2
                            WHERE (col1 = "value" AND col2 = "value")');

      $stmt->execute();
```

I create and dump the table because its part of an update script.

(Is there a better way to do that than dump/create?)

The script needs the current list of ids and I am trying to get create a table with those ids. What happens is, whenever I run the code (using putty) it returns "0" and the table remains empty.

What did I do wrong?

Any general help/advice concerning php/mysql welcome too!

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: @nl-x My problem is that the query does not work. Whenever I run it the table remains empty, no ids are added and in putty it returns "0" thats it, no errormessage(set my PDO settings to exception) nothing.

Comment: I think the schema design is very poor.

Comment: Have you checked for errors with `mysqli_connect_errno()` and `mysqli_errno()` ?

Comment: @nl-x: That won't work, since OP is using PDO. Try setting the error mode to `$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`, forcing PDO to throw exceptions upon error. Then catch the exception and look at the message

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Errr, my bad. Whatever the PDO equivilants are then...

Comment: @MeetM what is your suggestion to improve it?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I already did, no errors thrown in putty... When i specifically look at the errorInfo it only shows sqlstate 00000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure PDO is set to throw exceptions if a query fails:

```
$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Then, perhaps catch the exception (or let the exception halt the application) and see what is wrong.
I do believe your insert query is, erm, off:

```
INSERT INTO tblname (id)
SELECT tblname2.colname
FROM tablename2
WHERE col1 = "val"
```

Just seems ambiguous, and messy, even more: it seems unsafe. However, try this -equally messy- query:

```
INSERT INTO tblname (id) VALUES (
    SELECT colname
    FROM tblname2
    WHERE col1 = "val"
);
```

Last but not least, make sure you're running PHP version 5.3+, because prior to that version, PDO did not support multiple queries.

My suggestion, though, is *not* to use multiple queries for the INSERT query. Instead, I'd use a transaction and separate the select and insert query. I'd also add a safety-net to the `DROP TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE` queries, too:

```
try
{
    $con->beginTransaction();//DROP & CREATE:
    if ($con->exec('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tblname') === false)
    {//query wasn't executed
        $con->rollback();
        exit($con->errInfo());//error
    }
    if ($con->exec('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblname(...);') === false)
    {
        $con->rollback();
        exit($con->errInfo());
    }
    $con->commit();//alter tables.
    $con->beginTransaction();//INSERT TRANSACTION
    $stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO tblname (id) VALUES (:id)');
    $bind = array(
        ':id' => null
    );
    $select = $con->prepare(
        'SELECT colname FROM tblname2 WHERE col1 = :val1 AND col2 = :val2'
    );
    $select->execute(
        array(
            ':val1' => 'value1',
            ':val2' => 'value2'
        )
    );
    while ($row = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $bind[':id'] = $row['colname'];
        $stmt->execute($bind);//inserts row
        $stmt->closeCursor();//optional
    }
    $con->commit();//save changes to db
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    //rollback transaction
    $con->rollback();
    exit($e->getMessage());//show what went wrong, and exit.
}
```

Comment: first: Thanks for your answer! PDO is set to throw exceptions from the beginning, running 5.3+. Why exactly is my query "off" and "messy"and above all "unsafe", I am trying to understand what you mean by that and am willing to learn and improve!

Comment: @user3568224: By off, I mean ambiguous. The `insert` + `select` query doesn't read easily. I also don't know for a fact if that SELECT query will return anything, you also omitted the `VALUES` keyword. Executing all those queryies in one go just looks lazy to me. I'd much rather see some `IF [NOT] EXISTS` checks in the `CREATE/DROP TABLE` queries, and I'd also much rather see a transaction and rollback bit, as I've added to my answer

Comment: Passing a string to `prepare` creates a `PDOStatement` instance. Using prepared statements makes for safer queries, if you actually _use_ the features prepared statements offer: placeholders, for one. That's why I am passing arrays to the `execute` calls

Comment: I see what you mean, I just wasnt aware of the possibilities of "IF EXISTS", and how would it be "unsafe" given that i do not have any outside input? I am still learning how to write proper code... I get all of your code except for one small bit. Could you explain the if `(!$con-exec` part I dont understand why you use the "!"?

Comment: `PDO::exec` returns an int or bool. If it returns false, that means the query wasn't successful, and the code encountered an error. However, the `!` should be replaced with `$con->exec() === false`

Comment: So basically you used it to turn a "false" into a "true" to run the rollback/errorInfo right? Do you have any advice on reading material to learn PHP/SQL and other programming basics?

Comment: @user3568224: Well, `PDO::exec` returns an int, giving you how many rows were altered by the query. Dropping or creating a table however might return `0`, which is a falsy value. `!0` evaluates to true, so I changed the code to `$con->exec() === false`. On learning PHP, I suggest you start reading [the PDO manual](http://www.php.net/pdo). MySQL offers comprehensive docs, too, but it's quite messy and therefore tricky to navigate. As ever, though, the best way to learn is to try, fail, try again, fail again until you succeed

Comment: How long did it take you to learn php? Ah ok, I understand now. Thanks for your help, Im going to implement it now!

Comment: @user3568224: Hard to say. It depends on what your definition of _"knowing a language"_ is. I started to write PHP about 11 years ago, back in high school. I started using PHP professionally 4~5 years ago. You can learn your first language in a couple of months. If it's a second or third language, a coupe of weeks will do. To learn how to get the best out of any language, be it PHP, C or Python, well that's a never ending story. Languages change, they all have their own quirks, caveats and benefits. They each require their own mindset. Learning a new language is like moving to another country

Comment: Learning the language that is spoken there is something you pick up relatively quickly. Making friends takes a little longer, but to fully understand the culture is something that is next to impossible... same applies to programming: the syntax and core functions are finite, and you can learn them quite quickly. To internalize them in such a way that you know where and when to best use them takes practice. Experience is the only tool that helps you there. To know any language 100% is neigh on impossible: just when you think you're done, a new version is released, or a new extension is created

Comment: I will keep that in mind! I am really gald that there are people like you out there who make the entry in the coding world that much easier! Thanks again very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a keyword here to INSERT the value into the table, which is VALUES.
The correct syntax will be

```
 INSERT INTO tblname (id) VALUES
                        SELECT tablename2.colname
                        FROM tablename2
                        WHERE (col1 = 'value' AND col2 = 'value')
```

> The values should be into SINGLE QUOTES, tried and test myself and these 2 work for me every time.!

Comment: The use of double quotes is not an issue. Check [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-literals.html) => single and double quotes are interchangeable.